# DB queries in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

How do you write these queries in Rails 3 using ARel
1.

```
@all_widgets = Widget.all(:conditions => ['id != ? ', @widget.id] )
```

2.

```
existing = WidgetSku.all(:conditions => ['widget_id IN (?) AND sku_id NOT IN(?)', widget_ids, sku_ids ])
```

I am unable to figure out how to write the **!=** and the **NOT IN** part of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rails 3 accept almost the same notation
a.e.

```
.where(['id != ?', @widget.id])

.where("id NOT IN (?)", [1,2,3])
```

Comment: I know it works the way that you have told me, but I want to know the exact way of how to do it in Rails 3 syntax.

Comment: @Jatin, I think this is the exact valid rails 3 way to make the job done.

Comment: @PeterWong: Well If I have two conditions, then I would have to use AND, just like we do in Rails 2.3. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jatin, I think we could chain those where such as `.where(...).where(...)`